# Put text description adjacent to kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

Following [this example](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html#position), here's what I have

````
# iris
This section is about the iris dataset
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
kable(head(iris[, 1:2]), format = "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = FALSE, position = "float_right")
```

# mtcars
This section is about the mtcars dataset
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
kable(head(mtcars[, 1:2]), format = "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = FALSE, position = "float_right")
```
````

But the output looks like this:

[image]

How do make the *mtcars* section appear below the *iris* section?

Answer (score 3):

I guess `kableExtra` doesn't offer such functionality yet.

You can however resolve to **html**, and do the following with little effort:

````
---
title: "hi"
author: "me"
date: "March 23, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
options(knitr.table.format = "html")
```

```{r}
kable(head(iris[, 1:2])) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = FALSE, position = "float_right")
```
# iris
This section is about the iris dataset.

This could be a whole paragraph.
<p style="clear: both"></p>

```{r}
kable(head(mtcars[, 1:2])) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = FALSE, position = "float_right")
```
# mtcars
This section is about the mtcars dataset
````

The relevant bit is `<p style="clear: both"></p>`

Comment: +1 but I have to deselect this as my chosen answer.  If the table is large this method positions the table above the title and text which is undesirable.  This is a good hack for a quick and dirty solution, but I suspect there's a better solution using some CSS tricks I don't know.  Thanks

Comment: @Ben I am not fully sure - are you saying that you would like to have the text either above or side-by-side depending on the sizing? That might be another question. In any case here is a link to a css-tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp, basically this discusses `float` and `clear`.

Comment: Try your solution with `cbind(iris, iris)` instead of `iris[, 1:2]` and you'll see what I'm talking about.  Looks weird when the table is positioned above the heading for the section.  (I appreciate your help on this).  I can probably figure things out from here.

Answer (score 1):

Put text after the table, and also add line breaks.  Since the output is in html, it seems like it doesn't know how large the table is, and uses simple HTML tags to wrap around.  One solution, wrap it in a table with 100% width:

````
<table style="width:100vw">
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
kable(head(iris[, 1:2]), format = "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = FALSE, position = "float_right")
```
# iris
This section is about the iris dataset. 
</table>

<table style="width:100vw">
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
kable(head(mtcars[, 1:2]), format = "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = FALSE, position = "float_right")
```
# mtcars
This section is about the mtcars dataset. 
</table>
````